# Distribution of random variable given by SDE at some point in time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, soft-question, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Suppose we have an stochastic differential equation given by,

$$\mathrm{d}X = N(X,t)\,\mathrm{d}t + M(X,t)\,\mathrm{d}B,$$

where $B$ is a brownian motion. As far as I understand we can think of this as,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}X}{\mathrm{d}t} = N(X,t) + M(X,t)e(t)$$

for a noise sequence $e$.

If we have a standard ordinary differential equation then the slope of the function at some time is obtained by just plugging in the time. But here is looks like this things are a little more tricky.

It looks like we dont know the distribution of say $X^{'}(t_{0})$ until $t_{0}$ as it is dependant on $X(t_{0})$ which value is in turn related to the $X^{'}(t_{0}-\Delta)$ and so on.

If I got this right we have to think about the distribution of $X^{'}(t_{0})$ not only as random in the sense of a usual random variable but also that it depends on all the previous outcomes. So its distribution could be thought of as a composition of all the previous $X^{'}(t)$'s distributions.

Does this kind of reasoning make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's reasonable to talk about $X'$ since $X$ will not be differentiable in the calculus sense. Sample paths of $X$ will not have a slope. I think the most intuitive way to think of this equation is via a discretization and then simuation.

$X(t + \Delta t) - X(t) = N(X(t), t)\Delta t + M(X(t), t) \times \text{generate_normal}(\mu = 0, \sigma = 1) \sqrt{\Delta t}$

Note the $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ on the stochastic portion is essential, and also prevents division of this equation by $\Delta t$, as you would like to do if you wanted a slope.

Now given a deterministic implementation of $N(a,b)$ and $M(a,b)$ and some reasonable choice like $\Delta t = 0.001$, you can actually simulate sample paths of $X$. For example, defining $N = 0$ and $M = 1$ will make your program simulate Brownian motion.

And it's true that future values of $X$ will depend on past values. Once you simulate many sample paths, you can do stuff like take the average of the sample paths at time $T$.

Comment: Not only the values of the "derivative" but also the distribution of the "derivative" and hence the distrubution of the values of $X$ depends on past outcomes right? If we think about the "derivative" as a tangent tracing out the graph

Comment: Also I am awere of that the derivative does not exist in the usal sense, but only as some generlised function.

Comment: Consider a fixed distribution $X(0)$ as the starting distribution. Imagine it as some weighted cloud of particles on the real line, with weight according to probability. Of course none of the particles depends on historical information since you are at time $0$. Now run each particle separately through the simulator, but at each random event caused by $\text{generate_normal}$, it splits up into many smaller particles. At the end of the simulation, the terminal cloud represents the distribution at time $T$. Do you see that, given many particles, you end up with the same cloud every time?

Comment: Yes the "end distribution" is the same every time. And this distribution is dependant on the distributions at each step. If we change one of the distributions in the middle, we get a completeley different end distribution. This alo happens if we condition on say some time in the filtration. If we condition half time and get two different outcomes. Then the end distribution changes aswell.

Comment: There is no way to change any of the distributions in the middle without changing the initial distribution

Comment: Really? Shouldnt we get the same kind of behavior up until that time and then just the rest of the paths being effected by this change for the rest of the time?

Comment: I'm not sure how to further clarify this point besides saying that "distribution" is a purely deterministic concept, in the same way as "expected value". By analogy, think if it's sensible to talk about $E[X]$ as depending on the realized value of some simulation of $X$.

Comment: The idea I got was that the distribution of $dX$ at some time $t$, is not deterministic since it depends on the earlier outcomes, if one consider it as an "isolated" random variable. This is the case since it depends on $X$ at time $t$ via the SDE, which is random itself. But sure if one takes into accont that we can just "compose" all the distribution for each time then we get a distribution aswell yes, but what I thought I realised was that the distrubution of $dX$ conditional changes all the way up until $t$ for all values of $X(s)$ for $s<t$ and at $t$ is becomes a usual random variable...

Comment: ..which there plays the role of a "new" initial dist. in some sense. In essence the distribution of $dX$  at some time $t$ changes with time and becomes diffrent for different history i.e different $X(s)$ shere $s<t$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82919/discussion-between-mark-and-user8321).